# Strike Lightning Components - How to make picklist options overlap scrollable modal?

Tags: css, lightning-design-system

In my Lightning component I am using a [c:strike_multiSelectPicklist](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/tree/master/aura/strike_multiSelectPicklist) in a scrollable modal. I use the slds-scrollable as I show douzenz of the picklist in the modal.

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
    <div class="slds-scrollable">
        <ul class="slds-accordion">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.attributes}" var="attribute">
                <c:strike_multiSelectPicklist label="Filter volumes by" value="{!attribute.filters}" onchange="{!c.changeFilters}" placeholder="{!attribute.label + ' - Select values'}">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!attribute.values}" var="value">
                        <c:strike_option label="{!value}" value="{!value}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </c:strike_multiSelectPicklist>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nonetheless when a user opens a picklist I want the strike-options of the current focus to overlap the scrollable area to make them better visible. I have tried to add a overflow: visible basically everywhere but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like either a SLDS bug or a problem with Strike's implementation.

I would suggest editing the `strike-options` component. You will need to apply the right CSS z-index property (or the right class) on the `ui:scrollerWrapper` component or below.

I hope this helps,

Comment: Also, if this can wait, lightning:comboBox should be available in Winter '18: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_components_roadmap.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: Can't I fix this without modifying the external component? And no... I can't wait ;-)

Comment: Not sure you can avoid modifying it. Part of the problem could reside in the implementation of ui:scrollerWrapper (ui namespace will be deprecated at some point). I am not sure it holds the right SLDS classes underneath.

Comment: Which classes should I look for?

Comment: No clue sorry. I actually did a quick try by copy/pasting an expanded picklist template from the SLDS website inside a modal template and I experienced the same issue as you. This could be a SLDS bug after all.

Comment: I created an issue at the SLDS repo: https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/issues/483